# python: определить входит ли число/диапазон в диапазон от min до max и скорректировать диапазон

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, range

стоит 2 задачи

1. есть число `value` и диапазон `r = (min, max)`, требуется определить, попадает ли число в диапазон
2. есть диапазон `r1 = (min1, max1)` и диапазон `r2 = (min2, max2)`, требуется найти пересечение диапазонов

понятно что и первую и вторую задачу можно сделать через обычные проверки в лоб, типа

```
res = r[0] <= value <= r[1]
```

и

```
res = max(r1[0], r2[0]), min(r1[1], r2[1])
res = None if res[0] > res[1] else res
```

но может есть стандартные функции или функции numpy для этого? чтобы в код поменьше лишнего своего кода добавлять

Answer (score 5):

Для удобной работы с интервалами есть сторонняя библиотека [portion](https://github.com/AlexandreDecan/portion). Устанавливаем её:

```
pip install portion
```

На [гитхабе](https://github.com/AlexandreDecan/portion#documentation--usage) есть много примеров. Получить пересечение можно так:

```
import portion as P
r1 = P.open(5, 10)
r2 = P.open(7, 15)
res = r1 & r2  # (7, 10)
```

Проверить вхождение числа можно операцией `in`:

```
res = value in r1
```

Comment: первый вариант работает только с целочисленными диапазонами, для вещественных - нет - это главный недостаток данного `range` в данном случае, а нужно все таки универсальное средство, вернее даже более вещественное

Comment: при больших значениях первый способ будет высчитывать вечность

Comment: Ок, я убрал способ с `range`